# Why my htaccess for no-www and https doesn't work?

Tags: .htaccess, https, no-www

I've a problem with my `.htaccess` file. I want to redirect no-www to www and HTTP to HTTPS.

I've tried these files but they don't work...

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

And

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: When you state it "doesn't work", please state exactly what doesn't work - what happens? An error? Undesirable redirect? Nothing? Your second rule block should work. Make sure you've cleared your browser cache as any earlier erroneous 301 redirects are likely to have been cached by the browser.

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for your response. Nothing happens... If I don't put myself the "s" after http, the redirection doesn't work.
I've cleaned cache and cookies for my browsers (Safari and Chrome) and still the same.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? (If so, please post your entire `.htaccess` file in your question - with these directives in-place.)

Comment: @MrWhite No I don't have. Just theses about https and www

Comment: Try adding any nonsense to the start of the file - do you get an error? What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: @MrWhite I'm using Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) on a VPS.

Comment: And what happens when you type "nonsense" in the file? If you don't get an error then it suggests that `.htaccess` files are not enabled and must be enabled in the server config. eg. `AllowOverride All` in the appropriate `<Directory>` container.

Comment: Nothing happens. Maybe check the server config like you said @MrWhite

Comment: After change the value off "None" in apache2.conf file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf),
I've this :

`<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

But, I've an error message when I want to access to my website :  **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

I've cleaned my cache and cookies and nothing change. @MrWhite

Comment: Is `/var/www/` your DocumentRoot? Do you have any other redirects in the server config? Please confirm the current contents of your `.htaccess` file. Is the SSL cert installed directly on this server?

Comment: I've changed /var/www by /var/www/nameofmywebsite/html. It's in the directory I've my website and my .htaccess. My .htaccess contain : RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite/$1 [L,R=301] And yes, directly on the server. (Thank you for your support @MrWhite)

Comment: Those directives look OK. As a way to debug this, try temporarily commenting out your existing directives and use the following instead: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^https=` `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?https=%{HTTPS} [R,L]` (2 lines). You obviously still need the `RewriteEngine` directive at the top. Request a HTTPS URL (not HTTP) on your site, you should see a query string on the URL of the form `?https=` - what follows this?

Comment: @MrWhite It's `?https=off`

Comment: Ok, that certainly explains the redirect loop. However, this implies the SSL is managed by a frontend proxy and the SSL cert isn't actually installed directly on the application server (or there is some unusual setup)? Try replacing `%{HTTPS}` in that last `RewriteRule` directive with `%{ENV:HTTPS}` - what do you see now?

Comment: @MrWhite I've change and I've this in my htaccess 
`RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?https=%{ENV:HTTPS} [R,L]`
And I've nothing after `https=`

Comment: Ok, that is not unexpected. Try another one... instead of `%{ENV:HTTPS}` try `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}`. Now what do you see?

Comment: @MrWhite I see this : `?https=https`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem was that `.htaccess` files were not enabled in the server config. After setting `AllowOverride All` in the server config to enable `.htaccess` files, this resulted in a redirect loop...

You are getting a redirect loop because the `HTTPS` server variable is reporting "off" when HTTPS is requested. This implies you have a front-end proxy that is handling the SSL connection, and this is confirmed by the fact that the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header (that your application server is seeing) is set to "https". (The `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is set by the proxy server as the request passes through.)

This implies that the "private" connection between this proxy and your application server is over plain HTTP. But the connection between the proxy and the client is secured by HTTPS. This isn't necessarily a problem, however, it means you need to adjust your directives to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header instead of the `HTTPS` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing. It is often preferable to test with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support @MrWhite! That's work now!